# Nuget packages not found in VS2017 with configuration in file name

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, visual-studio-2017

My team has an internal Nuget package source in the form of a local folder synced to a NAS. The files have configuration (release/debug) and platform (always "AnyCPU") in the file name, e.g:

MyPackage.1.0.6017.25342.Release.AnyCPU.nupkg

This works fine in VS 2015 but in VS 2017 the packages aren't found by the package manager unless we remove the "Release.AnyCPU" part.

Does anyone know why? Can this be fixed?

Comment: Where did you find the packages by the package manager? Is it directly from the local folder or from the NAS? I have tested this package on the local folder on Visual Studio 2017, that works fine. If this restriction only exists on the NAS not on local folder, this issue may be more related to the NAS.

Comment: It's in the local folder, e.g. D:\Cloudstation\NuGet. All files are synked and works fine in VS 2015. If we remove "Release.AnyCPU" from the file name, they pop up in VS 2017.

Comment: what is your version of Visual Studio 2017? This package works fine on my Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise 15.0.0+26228.9, please update your Visual Studio first. Set the package to a common local folder without synced, check if it works fine.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this!
My VS 2107 version is 15.0.0+26228.9, Professional. 
I just did this test:
1. Created a new folder, D:\NugetTest\ and added it as a package source. 
2. Copied a few versions of the same package, Easyfy.Commerce.Model.1.0.x.x.Release.AnyCPU.nupkg, to the folder. 
3. Updated the list of packages in package manager, no versions of this package were visible. 
4. Removed "Released.AnyCPU" from three of the package files so they looked like this => Easyfy.Commerce.Model.1.0.x.x.nupkg. 
5. Updated the package list and those three versions were now available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the nuget package is composed of the package ID and the version when we pack a package. For example, Easyfy.Commerce.Model.1.0.x.x.nupkg. If you specify Configuration info into the name, the name of the package changed to Easyfy.Commerce.Model.1.0.x.x.Release.AnyCPU.nupkg, but the package ID the has not changed, is till Easyfy.Commerce.Model. In this case, **the package name do not match the package ID and version**, then the version of the package could not be list in package manager.

As test, you can open a package with NuGet Package Explorer, then change the package ID, you will get below prompting:

[image]

**To resolve this issue**, you just need to change your package ID to "`Easyfy.Commerce.Model.Release.AnyCPU`" by NuGet Package Explorer and change the package name to "`Easyfy.Commerce.Model.Release.AnyCPU.1.0.6017.25342`".

Besides, the reason for this issue occurred on the Visual Studio 2015 but does not occur in Visual Studio 2017 is that more restrictions in nuget 3.5 and later.

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying!